# What should be the extention of video to save to ParseFile on Parse

Tags: video, parse-platform, file-extension, sparse-file

According to the docs ParseFile requires an extension so to know what type of content it is handling. In my case user captures a video with her mobile device, then from the Uri of the video, I get the byte[] and pass it to ParseFile. What should the extension of my video be? I mean when I do

```
ParseFile videoFile = new ParseFile("videofilename",videoBytes);
videoFile.saveInBackground();
```

What should be the extension of `videofilename`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply specify it however you want:

```
... new ParseFile("nameofvideo.mp4", videoBytes);
```

Keep in mind Parse only supports files ≤ 10MB